# setActionView hides Menu Item

Tags: android, menu, android-progressbar

When trying to set a progressbar on my menu item , my menu item always gets hidden. I just want to use it for AsyncTask but currently I just made a little test setup. I am using an AppCompatActivity.

Menu :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        android:title="Refresh"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Progressbar (action_progressbar.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

</ProgressBar>
```

setActionView :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_refresh:

                MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.action_progressbar);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Any ideas ? I am running on 6.0 ( API 23) but should also run on > API 9 (MenuItemCompat)

Answer (score 0):

after

```
MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.action_progressbar);
```

try

```
item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
```